# retrieve matching elements in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [35635d5ebdd938d6360e65a9e2484073] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => 35635d5ebdd938d6360e65a9e2484073
            [id] => MYU_SC3
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 4800
            [name] => JAMB UTME Scratch Card
            [service_image] => assets/img/jamb.jpg
            [service_category] => cards
            [subtotal] => 4800
        )

    [d8df18561040f3d9bd9868f5c5aaa7c2] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => d8df18561040f3d9bd9868f5c5aaa7c2
            [id] => MYU_SC1
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 1600
            [name] => WAEC Scratch Card
            [service_image] => assets/img/waec.jpg
            [service_category] => cards
            [subtotal] => 1600
        )

    [a4a751dd9a69824eb3abb6f49c7a7f61] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => a4a751dd9a69824eb3abb6f49c7a7f61
            [id] => MYU_SC2
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 1600
            [name] => NECO Scratch Card
            [service_image] => assets/img/neco.jpg
            [service_category] => cards
            [subtotal] => 1600
        )

)
```

I want to retrieve the sub-arrays that match elements in another array

```
$card_skus = array("MYU_SC1","MYU_SC2","MYU_SC3");
```

Am looping through the main array

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $key => $item) {
      if(in_array($item['id'], $card_skus))
      {
       //Didn't know what to do at this point
      }
}
```

How do i get this done, thanks for the help

Comment: `$newArray[] = $item['id'];`?

Comment: Put this in your if statement: `$newArray[] = $item;`. Then do `var_dump( $newArray);` after the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess @nickb already answered in the comments, didnt see it while writing an answer.

Try this

```
$subArray = array();
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $key => $item) {
   if(in_array($item['id'], $card_skus))
   {
      //Didn't know what to do at this point
      $subArray[] = $item;
   }
}
```

Use $subArray now as per your requirement